# Using a grunt plugin's Gruntfile task rather than one from the executing Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

I have a grunt plugin, let's call it `grunt-my-plugin` and within the plugin's Gruntfile I have a specific `cssmin` task that needs to be run. Everything works as expected when testing the grunt plugin, however, when I install it on another project it gives me the following error:

`Warning: Task "cssmin" not found. Use --force to continue.`

At first, I was just calling `grunt.task.run('cssmin');` from the plugin's task file, but then after seeing the error I realized that the Gruntfile that uses this plugin needs to be pointed to the appropriate task config, so I added:

`grunt.task.loadTasks('./Gruntfile.js');`

That still have me the error, so I tried:

`grunt.task.loadTasks('./node_modules/grunt-my-plugin/Gruntfile.js');`

Still getting the error. So, how do I fix this? The plugin does not need specific config from a Gruntfile that uses it. The `cssmin` task is being used to create a tmp copy and run metrics against it. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following:

- your plugin has the `grunt-contrib-cssmin` plugin listed as a dependency in `package.json`
- you have `npm install`-ed in the other project (check with `npm ls grunt-contrib-cssmin`)
- supply configuration for the `cssmin` task using [`grunt.config()`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config) before calling `grunt.task.run('cssmin')` (see [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib/issues/118#issuecomment-8482130) for an idea)

Comment: That seems like a convoluted way to achieve this. Is there not a way to store the config externally and point to that?

Comment: I'm not sure that `grunt.task.loadTasks()` is what you need. Perhaps you could put the config in a `cssmin-config.json` file and then `grunt.file.readJSON()` it, iterate over the object it returns and pass each element to `grunt.config()`. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Appreciate it. The github linked you referenced is using Grunt 0.3, so I wonder if there's a better way to accomplish this in 0.4?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you may ask using IRC in [#grunt on irc.freenode.net](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=grunt). If you find a better way please share the idea here :)

Comment: After more digging, it appears that `grunt-contrib-cssmin` is not being installed in the other project even though I have it listed as a dependency in the plugin. Is there not a way to point to the plugin's dependency, or automatically add it (`--save-dev`) when the plugin is installed to the other project?

Comment: [This solved it for me](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/696#issuecomment-24346267)